# Unable to parse response error while uploading screenshots on google play (Android Market)

Tags: android, google-play, publishing

I just signed up with Market and uploaded my app. On the next screen, it is asking me to upload assets. After i choose screen shots for the app and hit upload, it gives me an error saying `"Unable to parse response. If you have a browser extension or add-on installedwhich changes the JSON response, please disable and refresh this page."`

I tried using Firefox, Chrome and IE but i am getting the same error.

On the Home page, it says

```
"Your Registration to Google Play is still being processed.
You can upload applications to Google Play but you cannot publish until your registration is completed.".
```

I guess this error has something to do with my registration as it is still in the pending stage. I dont know what do they want me to do in order to complete the registration.

If someone has faced this problem and was able to fix it, your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246270/registration-in-processed-on-google-play-in-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently the error is gone today. I sent them couple of emails and they replied back saying they have approved my registration. I guess its not them but it got fixed as the payment cleared from the credit card. If you have this issue, send them an email or wait till the charge is cleared off in the credit card.

Comment: How long did it take for them to reply?

Comment: 2 days. May be because it was weekend

Comment: Ah ok thanks, they got back to me in around 2 hours in the end

Comment: They also got back to me again within 1 working day (3 days including weekend in the middle)

Comment: I had the exact same issue. First I waited 3 days (including weekend). Nothing happend, so I contacted them. 2 days later it was ok. Haven't heard back from them what was wrong or that they've fixed it, just when they started looking into it.

Comment: Is `checkout-support@google.com` the email address they respond you from? I send them an acknowledge with this issue I also get, using Help - Upload Application- Contacting Support

Comment: I had the same problem. There was a problem processing the registration fee, which was rejected. I repeated the payment, which fixed the problem.