# Registration in processed on google play in android?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to parse response error while uploading screenshots on google play (Android Market)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752165/unable-to-parse-response-error-while-uploading-screenshots-on-google-play-andro)

I just signed up with Market and uploaded my app. On the next screen, it is asking me to upload assets. After i choose screen shots for the app and hit upload.

I tried using Firefox, Chrome and IE but i am getting the same error.

On the Home page, it says

**"Your Registration to Google Play is still being processed.
You can upload applications to Google Play but you cannot publish until your registration is completed."**

I guess this error has something to do with my registration as it is still in the pending stage. I dont know what do they want me to do in order to complete the registration.

Comment: not publish my apk in my account so what the porblem???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it happens due to slow upload speed of user network and also for heavy traffics of play store server. So i think you can wait couple of hours and then again can try it. This happens several times in my case also first time i have panicked also then found this is ok. :D

And there is no way you can speed up the registration process, it will be completed naturally.

Answer (score 3):

i got this solution wait for 1 week and send a message to google for your process of your order and google accept your request and publish your application.....